# I have a query in String in python

Tags: python

I would extract all the string contained in a list. Which is the better suited for the purpose??

Example:

```
line = "hello 12 hi 89"
```

Result:

```
[hello hi]
```

Comment: we can help you debug your code

Comment: "re" module is "better suited for the purpose".

Comment: Is that your homeworks you want us to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service!

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why you don't regard 12 and 89 as strings.

From your example, looks like you're trying to extract all the alphabetic tokens in a string, then you can use the expression `[a-zA-Z]+` to match 1 or more lower and upper English alphabets, and then call `re.findall()` on with the regular expression along with the input string:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input = 'hello 12 hi 89'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', input)
['hello', 'hi']
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this website especially the "**Accessing characters in strings by index in Python**":

http://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/

to get started try messing around with the following code:

```
line = "hello 12 hi 89"
line[0]
line[0:2]
```

good luck!